# Applozic video calling in Android

Tags: android, camera, video-streaming, call, videochat

On the website of Applozic it's given that video calling is possible by it's SDK. https://www.applozic.com/features.html

But there is no description in document of video calling.

```
if (id == R.id.dial) {

        ((ConversationActivity)getActivity()).processCall(contact,currentConversationId);
    }
```

This is the code which is calling on pressing call button but it is always taking conversation id null.

Also I don't find code in SDK related live video calling.Can anybody help please?

**Update**:- I did contact to Applozic support team they are planning to lunch video calling in some week.

Answer (score 3):

We have released audio/video call and you can get our sample [in github](https://github.com/AppLozic/Applozic-Android-Chat-Sample/tree/master/Applozic-Android-AV-Sample).

Audio-video gradle dependency:

```
compile 'com.applozic.communication.uiwidget:audiovideo:1.0'
```

You should follow our documentation for [how to enable audio-video call](https://www.applozic.com/docs/android-chat-sdk.html#audio-video-call-setup).